# Regex find text between

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will find me the following text:

```
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"
```

from an input like:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostik.nl\Users\_aliases]
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostikfindley.nl]
```

So I want it to grab everything from `\_alisases]` until the `'['` from the next `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` if that's possible. I will use this to output all the variable texts under this node in a text search program.

It's a big file with 18000 lines where I will search in using text search. There are also line which don't include the _aliases] they shouldn't be returned as valid.

Example:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostik.nl\Users\_aliases]
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostikfindley.nl]
"Address"="$virtual291"
"TopDir"="D:\\IMail\\bostikfindley_nl"
"Flags"=dword:00000000
"NotifyAddress"=""
"SubMailboxCreate"=dword:00000000
"NotifyPercent"=dword:00000000
"MaxOutboundSize"=dword:00000000
"VirusScan"=dword:00000001
"MaxSize"=dword:00000000
"MaxMsgs"=dword:00000000
"MaxRcv"=dword:00000000
"MaxUsers"=dword:00000000
"UserCount"=dword:00000001
"EnableSSL"=dword:00000001
"ForceSSL"=dword:00000000
"IcalEnable"=dword:00000001
```

I want only to be returned:

```
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"
```

This does have to be a regex i can use in Search and Replace tool to find the information I need.

Comment: It has to be exact? I mean, for example the email you want will always be "infonl@bostik.com" or it can be any valid email? Same goes for other values like "root".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't specified a programming language, here is a Perl script that do the job:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    if (/_aliases\]/ ... /\[HKEY/) {
        print unless /\[/;
    }
}

__DATA__
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostik.nl\Users\_aliases]
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\bostikfindley.nl]
"Address"="$virtual291"
"TopDir"="D:\\IMail\\bostikfindley_nl"
"Flags"=dword:00000000
"NotifyAddress"=""
"SubMailboxCreate"=dword:00000000
"NotifyPercent"=dword:00000000
"MaxOutboundSize"=dword:00000000
"VirusScan"=dword:00000001
```

**output**

```
"postmaster"="infonl@bostik.com"
"info"="infonl@bostik.com"
"nobody"="root"
```

Comment: Just say `print unless /\[/`; don’t use `$_`.

Comment: Thank you, I will port it to c# :)

Comment: @Younes: How can you port it to C♯ without a flipflop operator?  Ouch.

Comment: Well it's not like I can't find any other solution for that issue :). It's solved and I wrote output to a new file having the information I needed. Very good that you know c# doesn't have a flip flop operator. I just used a boolean in my loop ;).

Answer (score 1):

I would do a string replace on `\[.*?\]` with an empty string, the remaining string is your result.

EDIT:
oke apparently, you meant something else...

if you only want those 3 attributes try this regex: `\"(postmaster|info|nobody)\"\=\".+?\"`

Comment: @downvoter, why the -1? It did what the question was about before the edit? please explain...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($subject =~ m/"(.*)\[.*/s) 
$result = $1;
```

This works with perl. I am unaware of which language you are going to use so it may differ.

Edit : I saw you changed you original post so I will have to reconsider.

Edit 2 : It works with your example.